# Mongoose connection sockets closed

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using nodejs and MongoDB for the first time and I'm having trouble when I want to connect to the DB.

I read the quickstart from mongoosejs but it still doesn't work, here is my code (right now, all my code is only in one file) :

```
/***** Utilities *****/
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

app.listen(8080);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:8080/users');

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', function (error) {
    console.log('/**************** ERROR **************\\');
    console.log(error);
});

db.on('open', function () {
    console.log("Hello World!");
});

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    pseudo: String,
    password: String,
    email: String
});

var Users = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

/***** Passport *****/
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

/***** Building routes *****/
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    var pseudo = req.body.pseudo;
    console.log("/******************************\\") console.log(pseudo);
    res.send('Hello ' + pseudo + '!');
});

app.get('/users', function (req, res) {
    Users.find(function (error, users) {
        if (error) console.log(error);
        else res.render('users.jade', {
            users: users
        })
    });
})

app.post('/create_user', function (req, res) {
    var user = new Users({
        pseudo: req.body.pseudo,
        password: req.body.password,
        email: req.body.email
    });
    user.save(function (error, user) {
        if (error) console.log(error);
        else res.render('create_user.jade');
    });
});

app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
    passport.authenticate('users', {
        successRedirect: '/create_user',
        failureRedirect: '/login',
    }) res.render('login.jade

    );
});
```

I'm trying to get data from the login page and store them into one mongo database  but I'm when I start this file, mongo returns the following message:

MongoError: server localhost:8080 sockets closed
name: 'MongoError',
message: 'server localhost:8080 sockets closed'

I really don't know how to correct this error.
Where am I wrong? Is it because of a possible asynchronous problem?

Comment: You can't be running your express server and mongo on the same port.  Where is mongo actually running?

Comment: Woo, I hadn't even seen this detail...indeed, mongo is actually running on 27017. I tried and the page is now loading, even if I have no users stored in the DB...Thanks for your help!